# NullPointerException while running Coref Stanford

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I want to use the coreference resolution from Stanford NLP. I have downloaded the latest version 3.6.But when I run the following code, I am getting NullPointerException. I looked up in net, and few people seem to have to experienced the same problem, but no solution is mentioned. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
  props.put("dcoref.score", true);
  StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
  String sentence="Stanford University is located in California. It is a great university, founded in 1891.";
  Annotation document = new Annotation(sentence);

  pipeline.annotate(document);
  System.out.println(document);
  Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
  Set<Integer> set=graph.keySet();
  Iterator <Integer> it=set.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()) {
    CorefChain c=graph.get(it.next());
    System.out.println("CorefChain: "+c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException in the code ?

Comment: It would help if you could find which line # in your code the exception is thrown from and post the stacktrace, ideally highlighting in your code the line # in question.

Comment: I am getting it at this line: Set<Integer> set=graph.keySet();
I am new to java and not very comfortable in it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Then `graph` is null. Check why `document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class)` returns `null`.

Comment: Can we unmark this as a duplicate? How on earth is "I'm getting a null pointer exception in a specific library in a specific use case" a duplicate of "what is a null pointer exception"?

Comment: The answer to the question is, incidentally, that you need to include the `mention` annotator before `coref`. You should have a line `props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, mention, dcoref");`

Comment: @GaborAngeli I added the line which you mentioned. But when I am trying to print the graph, I am getting null. What am I missing? Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: The issue is that we have changed how dcoref results are stored.

Comment: You need these import statements:

Comment: import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;

Comment: import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.CorefChain;

Comment: We don't use: edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations any more

Comment: The line should be like this: Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class);

Comment: with these imports: import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.Mention;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.util.*;

Comment: With that set up I got your example to work.  In 3.6 we changed the details a bit...in short, dcoref and hcoref have to use the same type of key (or we'd have to rewrite a bunch of stuff), so I changed dcoref to use the hcoref keys...I suspect in your example you are doing import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.* or import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations...so don't do either of those.

Comment: Also there is a bunch of documentation on coref here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html

Comment: For instance you might want to use the "coref" annotator instead of "dcoref"...that link I provided has a bunch of info!